# Creating & Setting a Map into context through SpringEl

Tags: spring-el

As SpringEl doc. indicates, there is el syntax for creating a list which then allows me setting it into the context as below:

    `List numbers = (List) parser.parseExpression("map['innermap']['newProperty']={1,2,3,4}").getValue(context);` 

However, I am not able to find a way of doing the same thing for Map nor I can find it in the document.

Is there a short hand way of creating a map and then setting it to context?  if not, how can we go about it.

If possible a code snippet will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible yet: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9472

But you can do it with some util method, which should be registered as SpEL-function:

```
parser.parseExpression("#inlineMap('key1: value1, key2:' + value2)");
```

Where you have to parse the String arg to the `Map`.

**UPDATE**

Please, read this paragraph: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-functions.

From big height it should be like this:

```
public abstract class StringUtils {

    public static Map<String, Object> inlineMap(String input) {
       // Here is a code to parse 'input' string and build a Map
    }
}

context.registerFunction("inlineMap",
    StringUtils.class.getDeclaredMethod("inlineMap", new Class[] { String.class }));

parser.parseExpression("#inlineMap('key1: value1, key2:' + value2)")
      .getValue(context, rootObject);
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response.

Running the above snippet results in the exception below. I was trying to find doc. that talks about syntax on inlineMap function, but wasn't able to.  Could you refer me the link
<code>
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1022E:(pos 0): The function 'inlineMap' mapped to an object of type 'class org.springframework.expression.TypedValue' which cannot be invoked
</code>

Comment: Added sample how to use SpEL-functions.

Comment: I see.  This way looks promising.  Hopefully, this then allows me to do the following operation.  I will test it out

parser.parseExpression("map['innermap']['newProperty']=#inlineMap{'....').getValue(context);

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible (since 4.1, I think):

```
{key:value, key:value}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-inline-maps